# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta en Laravel con "where" y operadores?

Tags: laravel

estoy haciendo una consulta a la tabla "apuntes", y necesito que me sume el campo "importe" entre dos fechas (por ejemplo "2022-08-01" y "2022-08-30" incluidas).
Lo hago con la siguiente consulta:

```
$impTot = DB::table('apuntes')
  ->select(DB::raw('sum(importe) as total'))        
  ->where([
       ['fecha','>=',$fecIni],
       ['fecha','<=',$fecFin]
   ])
  ->get();
```

Pero si me voy a la tabla en mysql y hago la misma consulta, no me da el mismo resultado. He observado que en el caso de Laravel, aunque en el where especifico ">=" el dia "2022-08-01" no lo tiene en cuenta, lo hace a partir del "2022-08-02".

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?. Gracias.

Comment: usara la hora tambien?

Comment: Probá con `whereDate` en vez de sólo `where`. Y checkea la zona horaria del server, la bd y la aplicación si coinciden

Comment: Si, lo he probado también, con el mismo resultado. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez deberías intentar con el método whereBetween.

Te sugeriría acceder a este recurso
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131416/laravel-query-builder-wherebetween

```
$impTot = DB::table('apuntes')
->select(DB::raw('sum(importe) as total'))
->whereBetween('fecha', [$fecIni, $fecFin])
->get();
```

Comment: Gracias, he solucionado el problema. Me he dado cuenta que si uso la libreria Carbon para darle formato a las fechas es cuando da el error, pero si no la utilizo, y me baso en php exclusivamente, lo hace correctamente. Gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema. Me he dado cuenta que si uso la libreria Carbon para darle formato a las fechas es cuando da el error, pero si no la utilizo, y me baso en php exclusivamente, lo hace correctamente.

```
    $fecIni = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->get('fechaIni'));        
    $fecFin = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->get('fechaFin')); 
           
    $query = self::obtenerApuntes($fecIni,$fecFin,$campo);
```

Algo hace el formato dado por Carbon para que a la hora de interactuar con la tabla de mysql no funcione correctamente.

Gracias a todos por las contestaciones.